# How to convert a varchar to date in a select statement that is already converting from date to varchar?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, date, casting

I am trying to convert the return of this statement back to a date format. The statement below must stay in place but I also need to change the from VarChar to Date.. I hope that makes sense.

```
Convert(VarChar(10), DATEADD(s, [Submit_Date], '1970-01-01' ), 101) [Submit_Date]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
CAST(Convert(VarChar(10), 
             DATEADD(s, [Submit_Date], '1970-01-01' ), 101)  as Date) 
  [Submit_Date]
```